# Can an employment contract regulate relationships between employees?

Tags: contract-law, employment

[An answer to a Workplace question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/3801/25229) raised my curiosity. The idea is that a company could legally (contractually) forbid its employees to have a relationship.

Is this at all possible somewhere? (The discussion under that answer seems to point to the US).

How is "relationship" defined in such a case? Talking OK but holding hands not OK? Going to the cinema OK but sleeping together not OK?

Answer (score 2):

Contracts are allowed to address or stipulate anything that is not illegal.  Employers are generally allowed to apply restrictions that do not discriminate against protected characteristics.  I.e., unless there is a law against it, employers are almost certainly allowed to regulate the relationships between employees.

In the U.S. this is quite common.  For example, many companies have ["anti-nepotism" and/or "fraternization" policies](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/employee-rights-book/chapter5-7.html).  The former restricts employment of people with a (usually pre-existing) familial relationship.  The latter restricts *behavior that could be perceived as "dating."*  Sometimes the restrictions only apply to employees with a supervisor/subordinate relationship, but it is not unusual to see a blanket prohibition.

Comment: Interesting - work contracts in the EU cannot regulate anything outside the  employment law. Specifically, they cannot regulate anything which is not related to your **work**. In other words, the employment law states that A, B and C must be in place, and that D can be discussed within strict limits. Relationship between people are completely outside the official concerns of an employer.

Comment: Also: how is "relationship" defined? (this is the essence of my question)

Comment: @WoJ - For nepotism it is defined by law: E.g., legal marriage, children, relatives within some degree.  For fraternization it is the *appearance* that is at stake, and it most certainly bears on the workplace: If someone in a supervisory position *appears* to have a relationship with a subordinate then it colors all of their supervisory work as being unfairly biased towards that subordinate.  In this sense, practice and the policy align: If the relationship can be kept a secret, then there's no problem.  If it comes out, that's exactly when there is a problem.  One knows it when one sees it.

Comment: For some specific occupations such as accountants there are rules that apply inside the EU as well. When I was working for an auditing firm all employees (no matter the occupation) were required to know these rules and do a mandatory test to confirm their acknowledgment (in the Netherlands).